# Store data obtained using foreach loop from view into the database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

I am trying to store the values obtained from the form into the database. I am stuck where I do not know how to obtain the values individually from `foreach($questions as $row)` and store them into the database.

My database table has the following columns:

```
variantid | stepid | questionid | newquestion | radiovalues | description
```

When I click on save, I am trying to save all the details obtained from the view into the database. every value obtained with each loop of `foreach($questions as $row)` needs to get stored in a new row. I think I should be using `insert_batch`, but I do not know how I can put all the data into the array.

How can I proceed with this? The following is the code that I have written. I have not written anything in model as I am stuck.

```
 <form id="theform">
  <label for="variants">Variants:</label><br>
          <?php
          foreach($variants as $row)
          {?>
               <div class="form-group">

              <input type="radio" name="variants[]" checked="true" id="variants" value="<?php echo $row->variantid ?>"/><?php echo $row->variantname ?><br/>

         <?php }

          ?>


<div id='steplist'>
   <?php

     foreach($substeps as $row){
         ?>
               <div id='img_div'>
                 <input type="radio" name="stepid[]" checked="true" id="stepid<?php echo $row->stepid; ?>" value="<?php echo $row->stepid;     ?>"/><?php echo $row->stepname ?><br/>
</div>
    <?php
  foreach($questions as $each){
  ?><br><br>
  <input type="text" name="questions[]" id="questions<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>" value="<?php echo $each->questionname; ?>" readonly/><br/>
<input type="hidden" name="questionid[]" id="questions<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>" value="<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>"/>

<a id="addq">Add question</a>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="newquestion[]" style="font-weight:bold;width:100%;height:5%" id="new_questions<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>" /><br>

  <div class="radio" id="answer">
  <label style="font-weight:bold"><input type="radio" name="radioquestions[<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>][optradio]" value="no" required>no</label>
  <label style="font-weight:bold"><input type="radio" name="radioquestions[<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>][optradio]" value="probably no" required>probably no </label>
  <label style="font-weight:bold"><input type="radio" name="radioquestions[<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>][optradio]" value="unknown" required>unknown</label>
  <label style="font-weight:bold"><input type="radio" name="radioquestions[<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>][optradio]" value="probably yes" required>probably yes</label>
  <label style="font-weight:bold"><input type="radio" name="radioquestions[<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>][optradio]" value="yes">yes</label>
</div>
<textarea name="question1_text[]" id="description<?php echo $each->questionid; ?>" rows="3" cols="73"></textarea><br>
<?php
}
   ?>
  <?php
  }
  ?>

</div>
</form>
      <input type='button' value='Save' class='save' id='save' />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#save").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:"<?= base_url() ?>index.php/task/perform",
             data:$('#theform').serialize(),

               success:function(response){

            alert(response);

           }
         });
   });
 });
```

This is my controller:

```
public function perform(){
var_dump($_POST);
$variantid = $this->input->post('variants');
$stepid = $this->input->post('stepid');
$questionid = $this->input->post('questions');
$newquestion = $this->input->post('newquestion');
$radioquestions = $this->input->post('radioquestions');
$question1_text = $this->input->post('question1_text');

 $this->load->model('task_model');
 $result= $this->task_model->performdata();
 if($result){
 echo "Data saved successfully";
 }
}
```

### Update

Thank you for the quick reply. I changed the code according to the suggestion. How can I get these values into the controller and send them  into the database?

Comment: You can't have several <input> with the same id on your HTML. You are creating several inputs on the foreach and they all have the same id "variants"

Comment: Another problem, you have one foreach inside another(for questions and substeps) but you are using the same variable for them($row), since the inside foreach is using the same scope of the outside one, the $row will be overwritten.

Comment: show your model code `$result= $this->task_model->performdata();`

Answer (score 1):

The HTML inside the foreach is invalid as it is missing a closing div tag and your input does not have the correct `name` attribute, for multiple inputs you should use `variants[]` and not the same ID. Do it in this manner:

```
<?php foreach ($variants as $row) { ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="radio" name="variants[]" checked="true" class="variants" value="<?php echo $row->variantid ?>"/><?php echo $row->variantname ?><br/>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```